# Show that $2^{(p-1)/2} \equiv 1\: \mathrm{mod}\:p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fermat-numbers

Let $F_n = 2^{2^n}+1$ be the $n$th *Fermat number* for $n \geq 2$ and $p$ a prime factor of $F_n$.

How can I show that that $2^{(p-1)/2} \equiv 1 \:\mathrm{mod}\:p$?

Comment: did you mean $2^{\color{red}2^n}$?

Comment: did you mean $2^{2^n} + 1$? The only prime that can divide $2^{2^n}$ or $2^{n^n}$ is $2$.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was trying to understand, thank you

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2566411/2-cannot-be-a-primitive-root-of-a-prime-f-n)

Answer (score 1):

You can look to  [Legendre's symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) you may  state this theorem this way as well:

$$\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) \equiv a^{(p-1)/2}\ \pmod{ p}\;\;\text{  and } \left(\frac{a}{p}\right) \in \{-1,0,1\}$$.

where Legendre's symbol is defined as:

$$\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = \begin{cases}\;\;\,1 \text{ if } a \text{ is a quadratic residue modulo}\ p\text{ and } a \not\equiv 0\pmod{p} \\-1 \text{ if } a \text{ is a quadratic non-residue modulo}\ p\\\;\;\,0 \text{ if } a \equiv 0 \pmod{p}.  \end{cases}$$
And you may check [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/502089/156150) for more informations about the proof